# Combining rows based on the id in R

Tags: r, aggregate, analysis

My data,

```
Id|date1|date2   
1|2008-10-01|NA        
1|NA|2008-10-02     
1|NA|2008-10-03     
2|2008-10-02|NA
2|NA|2008-10-03
```

I want output this way,

```
Id|date1|date2|date3    
1|2008-10-01|2008-10-02|2008-10-03        
2|2008-10-02|2008-10-03
```

I tried using aggregate and dcast but they are making date into numeric format and na's are still not avoided.

Comment: So what happens if you have many dates in both ids? How do you decide which date goes where? Also, do you really want to create a limitless number of columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this quite easily using `data.table` though it will get more complicated if the number of non-missing values isn't equal between the columns

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, na.omit), by = Id]
#   Id      date1       date2
# 1:  1 2008-10-02 2008-10-02 
# 2:  2 2008-10-02 2008-10-02
```

Comment: thanks, but it is creating duplicate rows, I mean i want one id with one row, if the same id has 3 different values then it should add new column for the new value, that's the reason I was trying dcast, aggregate etc.,

Comment: Can you show an example data set and desired output?

Comment: for example id-1 is present in 4 rows, with different dates, then the output must be like id | date-1 |date-2 | date-3 | date-4 (one row for one id, but expanding columns)

Comment: Then please update your original question with desired output

Comment: @Maddy It may be better to use `toString` and concatenate the dates together as the lengths may be different in each `Id` and would still result in `NAs` in some columns by having separate columns

Comment: @akrun when I concatenated, dates are being changed into numeric format. But still if there are NA's in the table, I prefer to have seperate columns

Comment: `setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) toString(na.omit(x))), by = Id]` work fine on your data, though I'm truly pazzeled how you want to handle many different dates in many ids and what are you going to do with all these columns

Answer (score 4):

Here's a similar idea using `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  gather(key, value, -Id) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  spread(key, value)
```

Which gives:

```
#  Id      date1      date2
#1  1 2008-10-02 2008-10-02
#2  2 2008-10-02 2008-10-02
```